# MySQL - Show duplicated data from columns in different tables, when only one column is duplicated

Tags: mysql

I have such query which shows me nicely which product.model is duplicated:

```
SELECT product.model, product_description.name, COUNT( * ) AS Count
FROM product, product_description
WHERE product.product_id = product_description.product_id
GROUP BY product.model ORDER BY COUNT
HAVING Count >1
```

however I can't force this query to show content of product_description.name for every duplicated product.model , to compare product_description.name

I was trying to make IN on this result, but all I get is '#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)'. Any idea how can I process this result further?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a subquery to do that:

```
select 
    p.model, pd.name
from 
    product as p, product_description as pd
where 
    p.product_id = pd.product_id
    and p.model in (
        select p.model 
        from product as p, product_description as pd 
        where p.product_id = pd.product_id 
        group by p.model having count(p.name)>1)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I recieved "#1054 - Unknown column 'product.model' in 'group statement'" trying to use it. I'm sure I have such column.

Comment: @JakubBujak Sorry, just a typo... should use the alias instead of the full table name

Comment: I tried using your statement, but it seems that this query it too heavy for my DB - I get '2013 Lost connection error'. I tried to simplify it to minimum:***
    select 
    p.product_id
    from 
    product as p
    where 
    p.model in
 (select p.model 
     from product as p, product_description as pd 
     where p.product_id = pd.product_id 
     group by p.model having count(p.model)>1)*** but it still give me this error. Any idea how can I make it less heavy? I have 20k entries in product table

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your desired results, if you want to see which models have more than one record in the the product table, and then want to see the associated product descriptions, you could use `GROUP_CONCAT` to combine your descriptions.

```
SELECT p.model, group_concat(pd.name), COUNT( 1 ) AS Count
FROM product p
  INNER JOIN product_description pd USING (product_Id)
GROUP BY p.model
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
ORDER BY 3
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d92a/1)

There are other ways to do this to return in different rows, just depends on your needs.

Comment: Thank you. This gives me duplicated names in one cell. Can you tell me how I can have every description for duplicated model listed in separate row, with corresponding model in cell next to it? I'm looking for a best way to present this data.

Comment: @JakubBujak -- np, is this what you're looking for: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d92a/5 -- if you want them in separate rows, Barranka has a good approach.  Best regards.